# Batch File: Start two Processes Simultaneously then Kill Process 1 once Process 2 is Complete

Tags: batch-file, automation, terminate

I need to run two processes, Process1 and Process2 simultaneously using a batch file.

I managed to do that using the start command, as in:

```
start "PROCESS1" Process1
start "PROCESS2" Process2
```

Once Process2 is complete, I would like to terminate Process1.
At present, I do this by waiting for Process2 to complete then manually pressing CTRL+C on the Process1 batch window. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? did you know that there's a built-in site search facility at the top of the page? I would advise that you use it; your question is not unique, and as it stands, because you've shown no attempt at performing the task you've laid out, your question is nothing more than a direct code request.

Comment: @Compo, thanks for your reply although it is not very helpful. I did run a search before posting this question, but I could not find what I need: I can manage to get the processes to run simultaneously, but I still have to stop one process manually. If you feel my question is not unique, could you kindly add a helpful link to a similar question?

Comment: Your sentence staring with `Once...` claims, `Process1` ends on its own, while `Process2` needs to be terminated manually. The next sentence (starting with `At present...`)  claims the opposite: `Process2` ends on its own, while `Process1` needs manual termination. Please clarify. Another question: is the order the processes are started important?

Comment: And, I know that questions regarding how to terminate a process, when another has ended, has been asked and answered on a number of occasions before, so please try the search facility again. If you are not sure how best to use that search facility, it has a [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to assist you too. The code that you have posted makes no attempt at the task you've laid out in your question, so you are expecting us to help you to fix something you've not fully researched, and tested yourself. As you're not new here, you should have read through all of [ask] before.

Comment: First `start "PROCESS1" "Process1"`, then `start "PROCESS2" /WAIT "Process2"`, and last `taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq PROCESS2"`?

Comment: @Stephan, there was a typo in my question: Process2 stops automatically, Process1 needs to be manually terminated. Process1 needs to be started before Process2.

Comment: Then aschipfl's suggestion should work (depends on the exact type of the applications). If it doesn't, expand your question accordingly.

Comment: You not need to "start" the second process: `start "PROCESS1" "Process1" & Process2 & taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq PROCESS1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who provided helpful advice.

In case someone else comes across a similar issue, I am posting a solution that works for me, that essentially follows @Aacini's suggestion:

```
Start "PROCESS1" Process1
Process2
taskkill /T /FI "WindowTitle eq PROCESS1"
```

By not "starting" Process2, the task kill command is only executed after this process is complete.